# Probability of picking at least one least number

Tags: probability, probability-theory

You have marbles numbered $1$ to $n$ (Marble1, Marble2, Marble3,... so on).       Now you play a game. In step 1, you randomly pick a marble from this pile; if the selected marble is marble1, you keep it, else you discard it from the pile. Note that if you keep it (meaning it was marble1), then you do not put it back in the pile. In step 2, you again randomly pick a marble from the remaining ($n$) marbles and if the selected marble is marble2, you keep it, else you discard it. You repeat this exercise n times. We would like to find out, at the end of this exercise, what is the probability  that you have at least one undiscarded marble?

Approach:

Let E1 = Event that 1st marble is picked
E2 = Event that 2nd marble is picked and so on.

Here, E2 depends on E1, because what if Marble 2 is picked on the first round ? It will get discarded and there is no marble2 in 2nd round.

So, P(E2) = ((1/n) * (1/(n-1)) + ((n-2)/n  *  (1/(n-1)))
Here, we are taking pass and fail conditions for picking 1st marble in the first round. (n-2) because in the fail condition, we couldn't pick 1st marble, and we can't pick 2nd marble. So remaining n-2 marbles are left for first round.

But from P(E3), I am getting confused. Is this the right approach to use, so that we can get P(E1 U E2 U E3 U .... En) which is the answer that we need ?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  An obvious place to start would be to work it completely for some small values of $n$.

Comment: Define 'discard'.  Remove it altogether or return to pile?

Comment: Remove it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A possibly helpful way to think of this problem is to pick out all the marbles without looking at the numbers and put them in one single row of marbles. Then look at the row of marbles and see if it is of interest or not.

Comment: But , discard means removing it altogether, so in that case, does this hint still apply ? Because outcome of each round effects the outcomes of subsequent rounds isn't it ?

Comment: @Joker: Yes the hint still applies. Say you have $5$ marbles. If the order of the full row is $51324$, what do you do?  What if the order is $43152$...and so on. Which orderings cause you to keep at least one marble?

Comment: Orderings where atleast one number matches its index. 

So can I write atleast = 1 - (probability of picking all orderings where none of the numbers match their index)

A google search indicates that This is called as derangement. So 1 - probability of picking all derangements. ?

Comment: Yes. I didn't know if you had studied derangements. Good job finding them!